# Python aiogram при повторном "нажатии кнопки" бот выдает ошибку ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, telegram-bot

**

### Всем заглянувшим привет!

**
При повторной отправке комманды бот выдаёт ValueError: I/O operation on closed file как заставить его отправлять повторно цикл там написать или ? в сети ничего адекватного не нашел. InputFile вместо open пробовал.

```
from aiogram import Dispatcher, types
from createbot import dp, bot

#-------------------------------------------------
photo = open('f404.jpg', 'rb')
#--------------------------------------------------

async def commands_send(message : types.Message):
    await bot.send_photo (message.from_user.id, photo=photo, caption= 'text')

def register_handler_client (dp : Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(commands_send, commands=['send'])
```

За ранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

в общем разобрался, нужно открывать фото через with (почитайте про контекстные менеджеры) что почему то не указано ни в каких описаниях bot.send_photo. Должно выглядеть так:

```
from aiogram import Dispatcher, types
from createbot import dp, bot

async def commands_send(message : types.Message):
    with open('ppp.jpg', 'rb') as photo:
        await bot.send_photo (message.from_user.id, photo, caption= 'text')

def register_handler_client (dp : Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(commands_send, commands=['send'])
```

Всё работает чему я несказанно рад. Мне спасибо :)